# Projectile motion in a vacuum

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, projectile-motion

I got stuck on exercise 26, 566p in calculus by morris kline.

> 26. A projectile is fired at an initial velocity of 160 ft/sec. Find the angle of fire $A$ so that the projectile will strike a wall 480 feet away at the maximum possible height.

It's solution to the problem.

> $y = -\frac{16}{V^2\cos^2A}x^2 + x\tan A.\tag{10}$
> From (10) with $V = 160$ and $x = 480$, we find the height $y$ is given in terms of the firing angle $A$ by $y = -144\sec^2A + 480\tan A$. Setting $\frac{dy}{dA} = 0$ and noting that $\sec^2A \not= 0$, we obtain the condition $\tan A = \frac{5}{3}$. Thus $A = 59\unicode{xB0}$(approx.).

The logic of the solution is followable. But when a projectile is at the max height, $x$ coordinate is one half of the range. Range of certain projectile with initial velocity $V$ and inclination $A$ is $\frac{V^2}{32}\sin 2A$. This implies with $V = 160$, range is at most 800 and therefore $x$ coordinate with maximum height is at most 400. But the exercise gives 480 which is greater than 400. So inserting $V = 160$ and $x = 480$ in (10) is nonsense. Is the exercise wrongly designed? Or am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the solution they have provided is correct!

[image]

They have clearly mentioned that **there is a wall** at $x = 480$
So, now you should make this clear that the maximum height of the projectile should reach at $x = 480$.

Now, They want you to have a projectile angle A for which your projectile will have max. height at $x=480$. that **does not mean that the height of projectile @$x=480$ should exceed the height of projectile @$x=400$**

[image]

The above graph shows traces of points (A<sub>y</sub> < B<sub>y</sub>)

Of course!, As you said the y<sub>mx at x=400</sub> > y<sub>mx at x=480</sub> is right.

But they only mean the maximum possible height at which the projectile can hit the wall.

Means,

say at angle $A = $a<sub>1</sub> y<sub>mx at x=480</sub> $=$y<sub>1</sub>

keep doing this way now for what value of angle $A$
you'll hit the wall max

Which Of course! the value of y<sub>mx (x,A)=(480,a)</sub> will never exceed y<sub>mx @x=400</sub> for whatever value of angle $A$

Comment: I agree with what you said. But my argument is that the distance between a wall and the origin should lower than or equal to 400 where $V = 160$ because the projectile have to hit the wall at the maximum height. I think the value of the distance is beyond its range. How do you think about this point?